# PHP filesize of dynamically chosen file

Tags: php, filesize

I have a php script that needs to determine the size of a file on the file system after being manipulated by a separate php script.

For example, there exists a zip file that has a fixed size but gets an additional file of unknown size inserted into it based on the user that tries to access it. So the page that's serving the file is something like getfile.php?userid=1234.

So far, I know this:

```
filesize('getfile.php'); //returns the actual file size of the php file, not the result of script execution

readfile('getfile.php'); //same as filesize()

filesize('getfile.php?userid=1234'); //returns false, as it can't find the file matching the name with GET vars attached

readfile('getfile.php?userid=1234'); //same as filesize()
```

Is there a way to read the result size of the php script instead of just the php file itself?

Comment: I have wondered this too, I have the feeling it's either a no, or something more complex than the above code.

Comment: i guess, you can do this using AJAX in the script tht you use determine the size of a file if i am able to understand your question properly.

Comment: If there is no way for you to know the filename, things get tricky. You might me able to look into finding the newest file, that might work for your case.

Comment: Does the `getfile.php` outputs the path to the file or the file itself ?

Comment: getfile.php creates a temp file, outputs that file, then deletes the temp file, so the actual file being output no longer exists on the file system once the requesting script gets the results.

Comment: @HotN stupid question: why can't you just add code to getfile.php that checks and logs the filesize before deleting it?

Comment: Since getfile.php does not return the result file, but create and destroys it on the server, the suggestions of using curl or otherwise getting the getfile.php wont work (they will either return the size of the php file, or its stdout). You need to either check the filesize while it exists OR try to analyze the script (which may be impossible to do programatically, because PHP is turing complete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone had posted an option for using curl to do this but removed their answer after a downvote. Too bad, because it's the one way I've gotten this to work. So here's their answer that worked for me:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/getfile.php?userid=1234');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //This was not part of the poster's answer, but I needed to add it to prevent the file being read from outputting with the requesting script
curl_exec($ch);

$size = 0;

if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $size = $info['size_download'];
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $size;
```

Comment: Though, I should note that I will happily change my method if I can, as this is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

[filesize](http://php.net/filesize)

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with some URL
>   wrappers.

something like

```
filesize('http://localhost/getfile.php?userid=1234');
```

should be enough

Comment: While this is hardly useable for practical purpose. The OP probably wants to show the filesize for the user before downlaoding. What this call does is start a web request, execute the script and generate the download file, then transfer the download file into memory and get the size. This is really expensive.

Comment: I tried this approach and it throws a warning and returns false.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the size of the output is to run it and then look. Depending on the script the result might differ though for practical use the best thing to do is to estimate basd on your knowledge. i.e. if you have a 5MB file and add another 5k user specific content it's still about 5MB in the end etc.

Comment: It's kind of an awkward business requirement, but the file size is handed off to another component of the system, which expects an exact size match when it requests the file again. Close doesn't quite count here.

Comment: Well then the best thing is to generate the file in the script where you need the size and store the generated file in some "cache" directory and on next request deliver the file. This also has the benefit, that you can leave the file delivery entirely to the web server and don't need a PHP script for that (but you need some cleanup job to get rid of old files)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Ivan's answer:

Your string is 'getfile.php' with or without GET parameters, this is being treated as a local file, and therefore retrieving the filesize of the php file itself.

It is being treated as a local file because it isn't starting with the http protocol.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php for supported protocols.

Answer (score 0):

When using filesize() I got a warning:
Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for ...*link*... in ..*file*... on line 233

Instead of filesize()  I found two working options to replace it:

1)
$headers  = get_headers($pdfULR, 1);
$fileSize    = $headers['Content-Length'];
echo $fileSize;

2)
echo strlen(file_get_contents($pdfULR));

Now it's working fine.